# If a fighter learns the Command spell from the Fey Touched feat, what is the spell save DC?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, fighter, difficulty-class

When you have the Fey Touched feat, you learn *misty step* and one enchantment or divination spell.

What is the spell save DC for the Wisdom saving throw against the *command* spell, when you are a fighter who learns it via the Fey Touched feat?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### It uses your spell casting ability like other spellcasters

The last line of *Fey Touched* says:

> The spells' spellcasting ability is the ability increased by this feat.

So that can be your Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma; depending on what you chose.

In the chapter on casting spell, under [Saving Throws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#SavingThrows):

> The DC to resist one of your spells equals 8 + your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus + any special modifiers.

So if you chose Charisma as your +1 for Fey Touched, the DC to resist *command* would be: 8 + Charisma bonus + proficiency bonus

It would work the same way even for spellcasters. If Wizard took Fey Touched, but used it to boost Charisma, then it would still use the Charisma bonus, and not their normal Intelligence DC. The DC is based on the ability boosted.

Comment: Afaict, every (first-party) feature that grants the ability to cast any spell will tell you what the spellcasting ability is (or require a feature that does)

Comment: @Caleth. correct. Even spells that don't have a saving throw element to them, such as gaining _misty step_ from _fey touched_, will still be associated with one ability score so any character can come up with a DC.